# overloading the indexer causes : "Minesweeper.Tile is a type but is used like a variable" error

Tags: c#, indexing, operator-overloading

I am making a minesweeper project in c# for fun and I wanted to store the new Tiles in a dictionary inside the Tile class so that when a Tile is initiated it is stored and can be accessed through Tile[coords] however I keep getting the above error. This is the code I am using for the Tile class (please don't comment on my conventions, I'm new to C# I'm a Java/Python programmer :p)

```
class Tile
{
    private static Dictionary <Coords, Tile> tiles = new Dictionary <Coords, Tile> ();

    public int numMinesAdjacents { get; set; }
    public readonly bool isMine;
    public readonly Coords position;

    private Tile [] aAdjacents = new Tile [8];

    public Tile(int x, int y, bool isMine = false)
    {
        this.isMine = isMine;
        position = new Coords(x, y);
        Tile[position] = this;
    }

    public void init()
    {
        calculateAdjacents();
        calculateNumMinesAdjacent();
    }

    private void calculateAdjacents()
    {
        int i = 0;
        for (int y = -1; y < 1; y++)
        {
            if ((position.y - y) < 0 || (position.y + y) > Math.Sqrt(Program.MAX_TILES)) continue;
            for (int x = -1; x < 1; x++)
            {
                if ((position.x - x) < 0 || (position.x + x) > Math.Sqrt(Program.MAX_TILES)) continue;
                aAdjacents [i] = Tile[position + new Coords(x, y)];
                i++;
            }
        }
    }

    private void calculateNumMinesAdjacent()
    {
        int n = 0;
        foreach (Tile pTile in aAdjacents)
        {
            if (pTile.isMine) n++;
        }
        numMinesAdjacents = n;
    }

    /*private static void add(Tile pTile)
    {
        tiles.Add(pTile.position, pTile);
    }*/

    public /*static - if I use static nothing is different*/ Tile this [Coords coords]
    {
        get { return tiles [coords]; }
    }
}
```

if I call

Tile(0, 0);
Tile(0, 1);

and then

Tile[new Coords(0, 0)]

I get an error, I also get an error in the places in the class where Tile[] is used (constructor and calculateAdjacents) what is going wrong here?

Thanks,
Jamie

EDIT: Sorry I meant Tile[position] I was changing it back and mistyped. The problem is I overloaded this which should mean that Tile[coords] is legal even when called from another class

Comment: The error is occuring on the line `Tile[this]` correct? Your array variable name is `aAdjacents`, not `Tile`, which should be why you are getting the error. Not to mention that `this` refers to an instance of `Tile`, while is not a specified indexer for your array (which expects int) or your custom indexer (which expects `Coords`)

Comment: you implement indexer like this. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6x16t2tx.aspx

Comment: Sorry! I meant Tile[position] = this;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not clear what you expect this to mean:

```
Tile[this];
```

It's not a valid expression at the moment though.

C# doesn't support static indexers. For an *instance* indexer, you could use:

```
Tile tile = this[someCoordinate];
```

... although it's odd for an *instance* indexer to use a *static* member like this. It would be cleaner just to have a method:

```
public static Tile GetTile(Coords coords)
{
    return tiles[coords];
}
```

Then you'd just call `Tile.GetTile(...)` elsewhere.

As a side-note, you should start following .NET naming conventions to make your code easier to understand. Also, I'd strongly recommend that you avoid public fields, even if they're read-only.

Comment: ahhh that makes sense to use this. But when I use Tile[] elsewhere should I use a dummy constructor? like Tile() which does nothing, just to use that functionality?

Comment: @J_mie6: No - you should basically not have an indexer which *tries* to be static. Just write a method instead. I'll edit my answer to indicate this.

Comment: hmmm, aside from Python (where static access is allowed), that's what I have always done, but I wanted to play with operators again.

what's the problem with the readonly fields? I would have used properties but then the problem is I need a set; or initialise, but I want it read-only. readonly was the only way I could think of initialising in the constructor and then making it constant.

Comment: @J_mie6: Fields are an implementation detail, and shouldn't be exposed in the API. To make a read-only property, you can have a read-only field and then a property with only a getter to return it. (Or you can have a property which only has a private setter, but that's not quite as clean.)

Comment: but surely, you can't tell the difference haha. It's one of those weird new conventions in c# that I have to learn about, and just accept. Not that I like properties in the first place, getter and setter methods look more friendly to me, properties look untidy but I have to compromise. thanks for the answer and help!